# How to loadChildren async with angular-router-loader

Tags: angular, angular-router-loader

I have folder structure like:

```
 - app
   -core
   -vacancy
```

in `core` folder I have `app.routing.ts` where I would like to async add route to vacancy.

I did it like:

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
        {
            path: 'vacancy',
            loadChildren: '../vacancy#VacancyModule'
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            component: NotFoundComponent
        }
    ], {useHash: true}
);
```

i get an error:

> Can't resolve '..\vacancy'

dispite the fact there is folder vacancy in folder `app` and inside of vacancy there is a file `vacancy.module.ts` which ` looks like:

```
// some imports here
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        VacancyBaseComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
})

export class VacancyModule {
    public static routes = routes;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late. In case you haven't figured it out, try this:

```
loadChildren: 'app/vacancy/vacancy.module#VacancyModule'
```

Answer (score 0):

UPD: actual time 2022-12-26

In Angular version 8, the string syntax for the loadChildren route specification was deprecated in favor of the `import()` syntax. You can opt into using string-based lazy loading (`loadChildren: './path/to/module#Module'`) by including the lazy-loaded routes in your tsconfig file, which includes the lazy-loaded files in the compilation.

By default the Angular CLI generates projects with stricter file inclusions intended to be used with the import() syntax.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#create-a-feature-module-with-routing